# How to show username from another table on the basis of max id in sqql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trapped in a sql query, I know it may be common but not getting any proper solution.
From my table `messages`, I have successfully fetch max id by joining `from` and `to` columns, now what I am trying to do is, I want to pull the `name` of that max id from another table naming `users`,

Here is my working query to find max id,

```
select m.* 
from messages m 
where m.id in (select max(m.id) as max_id 
               from messages m 
               where m.`from` = 7 
                  or m.`to` = 7 
               group by least(m.`to`, m.`from`), greatest(m.`to`, m.`from`))
```

I have tried something like this but it matches name with `from` column of `messages` table.

```
select messages.*, users.name 
from messages 
left join users on messages.`from` = users.id 
where messages.id in (select max(id) as max_id 
                      from messages 
                      where `from` = 7 
                         or `to` = 7 
                      group by least(`to`, `from`), greatest(`to`, `from`))
```

I want that name will be shown according to max id that I am getting.

columns of `messages` table : id , from, to, created_at

columns of `users` table : id, name, email, created_at

Please help me out,

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output

Comment: Specify MySQL version. Does `messages.id` is unique (maybe even primary key)?

Comment: @Akina, yes its unique

Comment: MySQL version is too confidential?

Comment: its 5.0, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to `join`, but only to the column that is not `7`:

```
select m.*, u.name
from messages m join
     users u
     on u.id in (m.`from`, m.`to`) and u.id <> 7
where m.id in (select max(m.id) as max_id
               from messages m
               where 7 in (m.`from`, m.`to`)
               group by least(m.`to`, m.`from`), greatest(m.`to`, m.`from`)
              );
```

Comment: its working but only when its 7, but when I put 6 its not working. Just replace 7 with $from

Comment: @BhaweshBhakar . . . You have to replace all the `7`s in the query with `6`s.  There is no reason it would work for one value and not another.